# SQL: Handling multiple SELECT conditions?

Tags: sql, select, dynamic

I'm just an basic SQL user (mySQL+php now). I have search box with multiple input (conditions).

For example:

Color: ***_*___**
Size: **__*_*_**
Price: ***_*__**
Condition: **__*_***
Discount %: ***_*__**
Hit Count: **__*_***
etc, many more ............

User may input 1 or more fileds.
Result should be filtered for multiple input also.
So, how can i handle this multiple conditions in Query?

I'm confusing how to write query (in former way):
`SELECT * FROM _item_ WHERE color='silver' AND/OR .... ... ?????`
????

A simple sample please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to have a base query, that even without filter criteria, still returns results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _item_ 
WHERE 1=1
```

this then allows you to easily add additional criteria to further filter your results, based on what was specified in the user interface. So, if someone says they want to filter on the color "silver" and the condition "new", we just add these to the `WHERE` clause of our query:

```
SELECT *
FROM _item_
WHERE 1=1
AND color = 'silver'
AND condition = 'new'
```

each additional filter criteria can just be added with an `AND` to the end of the base query.

**edit:** as pointed out in other posts, this is a naïve approach and you need to be careful of SQL injection, but the original question asked for a simple example and this was as simple as I could think of.

Comment: I would suggest this method with one caveat : Use parameterised queries to let the sql engine cache execution plans AND to protect from sql injection.

Comment: Your query is simply best, ninesided. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no one simple solution. You could create dynamic SQL from scratch based on the parameters or you could use some a different SP for each combination of parameters or you could just get everything then filter in your client side or...

But be very careful about SQL injection.

I would suggest, before going any further, you read something like http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html and 
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html which give a lot of detail about this sort of thing. Long but worth it.

Comment: +1 : Although those references are long, it's because it is actually a difficult problem to solve *efficiently* in a single generalised way.  The short answer is, write Dynamic SQL - But the article does mention certain things to be careful of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COALESCE to dynamically construct the WHERE clause, if the supplied parameter is null then column value will be used instead so you just need to ensure that you pass null where appropriate:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE color = COALESCE(@Color,color)
AND condition = COALESCE(@Condition,condition)
```

Note that this assumes the use of a parameterised query so should be pretty SQL Injection proof.

Comment: I'd have to test this to be sure, but I think this will result in a full scan of the entire table every time - making no use of indexes what so ever.

Comment: I'm not sure about MySQL but my implementation of this query in SQL Server 2000 uses the indexes with no table scans.